# How do I get git:(master) npm to run? zsh brings back "number expected"

Tags: git, npm, zsh

I'm new to coding and have been doing a few different tutorials here and there. Right now I'm doing JavaScript Full Course for Beginners by Amigoscode.

I got the git close from his repository to unpack,

```
Last login: Sat Sep 11 12:16:25 on tty

UserUser -MacBook-Pro ~ % git gh repo clone amigoscode/javascript
Git: ‘gh’ is not a git command. See ‘git - -help’. 

The most similar command is 
        gc
UserUser@-MacBook-Pro ~ % git repo clone amigoscode/javascript
Git: ‘repo’ is not a git command. See ‘git - -help’. 

The most similar commands are 
        grep 
        reflow
        remote 
        repack

UserUser@-MacBook-Pro ~ % git clone amigoscode/javascript 
Fatal: repository ‘amigoscode/javascript’ does not exist

UserUser@-MacBook-Pro ~ % git clone https://github.com/amigoscode/javascript.git
Cloning into ‘javascript’…
remote: Enumerating objects: 98, done. 
remote: Counting objects: 100% (27/27), done. 
Remote: compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done. 
Remote: Total 98 (Delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 71 
Unpacking objets: 100% (98/98), done.
```

but I cannot get the `git: (master) npm` to run.

My zsh brings back an error that says "number expected".

```
Last login: Sat Sep 11 12:52:07 on ttys000

~   git:(master) nom 
zsh: number expected 
    
    
~   git:(master) nom 
zsh: number expected
```

I tried looking for a solution on Stack Overflow.
One post suggested closing the terminal window, but that did not work.

Has anyone encountered this issue?
How can I get the `git: (master) npm` to run?
I'm on macOS Catalina version 10.15.7, git version: 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `git gh` would not work indeed.
`gh` is a command on its own, the [GitHub official CLI](https://cli.github.com/)

To clone a GitHub repository with it, you would use [`gh clone`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_clone) (assuming [`gh` was installed first](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation)):

```
gh repo clone https://github.com/cli/cli
```

No `git` in front of it.

If you clone `https://github.com/amigoscode/javascript`, you need then to cd to the `javascript` folder created by the clone operation, before trying `npm`.
Type first `which npm` to check that executable is part of your `$PATH`.

Note that `git: (master) npm` is not a command.

- `git: (master)`  should be part of the prompt (as explained for instance in "[Simplest ZSH Prompt Configs for Git Branch Name](https://medium.com/pareture/simplest-zsh-prompt-configs-for-git-branch-name-3d01602a6f33)") by [Nick Gibbon](https://uk.linkedin.com/in/nick-gibbon-b87121172))
- `npm` should be what you are typing.

---

[The OP ade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16141113/ade) confirms/explains in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69145294/how-do-i-get-gitmaster-npm-to-run-zsh-brings-back-number-expected/69146306#comment122701532_69146306):

> I figured out what I was doing incorrectly and you are correct.
> I was using the wrong command in the terminal.
>
> Once I used the correct command (`git clone`) to download the repo, I was able to use the command '`npm intall`' to install the correct `npm` version to install the dependencies and run '`npm run devserver`' to connect to the `localhost:3000` where the front end of tutorial was housed.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I figured out what I was doing incorrectly and you are correct. I was using the wrong command in the terminal. Once I used the correct command (git clone) to download the repo, I was able to use the command 'npm intall' to install the correct npm version to install the dependencies and run 'npm run devserver' to connect to the localhost3000 where the front end of tutorial was housed.

Comment: @Ade Well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.